# Integer solutions to $2^m - 3^n = p \cdot C$ where $m, n , p$ are positive integer variables and $C$ is a positive integer constant.

Tags: number-theory

How many solutions are there for equation  $2^m  -  3^n = p \cdot C$ where $m, n, p$ are positive integer variables and $C$ is an odd positive integer constant greater than $3$?

Can we say that if there will be none, one, finitely many, or infinite number of solutions?

What happens if $C$ is prime? We believe that for prime $C$, there is at least one solution. Can we prove it?

Comment: You shouldn't say "infinite solutions" when you mean "infinitely many solutions." If you have four solutions, each of which is, by itself, an "infinite solution" (whatever that is), then you have _infinite soltuions_ but not infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Are you solving for $n,m,$ and $C$ with $p$ fixed, or for $n$ and $m$ with both $p$ and $C$ fixed? $\qquad$

Comment: There are no solutions in $m,n,p$ if the constant $C$ is a multiple of $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, $C > 3$

Comment: solving for $m, n, p$ which fixed $C$

Answer (score 0):

Bennett has proved the following result, see [here](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ebennett/B-CJM-Pillai.pdf):

*Theorem:* Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers with $a,b\ge 2$. Then
$$
a^m-b^n=c
$$
has at most two positive integer solutions $(m,n)$.

For example, the equation $2^m-3^n=5$ has the two solutions $(m,n)=(3,1),(5,3)$.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have seen Bennett's paper where he is solving for $m, n$ and $c$ is fixed. My problem has an additional variable $p$.

Answer (score 0):

IF $p$ is variable integer, then for a pair $(m,n)$ there exists some $p$ such that
$$2^m-3^n=pC$$
if and only if
$$2^m=3^n \pmod{C}$$

It is also easy to argue that there are infinitely many solutions of this second equation.

If $p$ is fixed, the other answer addressed this.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions. Let $C=11$, $n=1$ and $m=10l+8,\exists   l\in\mathbb{N}$ then $$2^{m}-3^n\equiv 2^{10l+8}-3\equiv 2^8-3\equiv 0\pmod{11}$$
and thus, we can let natural number $p=\dfrac{2^{10l+8}-3}{11}$ so that $(m,n,p,C)=(10l+8,1,1,11)$ are the solutions to the equation $2^m-3^n=11k$ $\Box$

---

And when $C$ is prime we can let $m= (C-1)q_1$ , $  n=(C-1)q_2$ for some natural number $q_1,q_2$ so that, by Fermat's little theorem
$$2^m-3^n\equiv1-1\equiv 0\pmod {C}$$
and choose $p=\dfrac{2^{(C-1)q_1}-3^{(C-1)q_2}}{C}$ that are the solutions to $2^m-3^n=pC$ where $C$ is prime, Hence, again there is infinitely many solution for prime $C$.